# Avoid jvm crash logs

Tags: java, jvm, crash

My java app keeps crashing the jvm every time its closed.
I think the crashes are caused by a third party dll im using, so i cant fix them.
The problem is that a hs_err _pid.log log file is created on every crash, filling the CWD.
Can be jvm crash logging disabled? Is there a way to do that from inside the running java app?
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, the VM version is 14.0-b16

Comment: Sorry, I phrased that poorly, that's the VM build version. Which java version is it?

Comment: Looks like that java6, so my answer below should be useful.

Comment: Effectively its java6, your Answer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In java 6, you can use the -XX:ErrorFile option to control where the file goes. I'm not sure if you can turn it off, but you probably direct it to /dev/null

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/trouble/TSG-Desktop/html/felog.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solves partially my problem, i will redirect log files to temp folder in windows xD